# Relationship between angles and intersection point

Tags: geometry

I was investigating the fifth postulate of Euclid, which says:

"If two lines are drawn by a  line, they intersect on the side where the added interior angles are less than 180, so $a + b < 180º$

Then, I realize that there is a relationship between the midpoint of those interior angles and the angle of intersection of the lines, and I believe that here I have discovered the concept of height, which according to my demonstration is: $h = \sqrt{a^2 - \frac{l^2}{4}}$, represented in this image:

[image: Image of my work]

Now I get a question more complex, which is the formula that relates the angles, with the length of the height?

I have noticed that there is also a close relationship, which you can see here:

[image]

For a better understanding of me, I left a fixed angle $ a_1 = 90, a_0 = 90 $.

When $b_1, b_0 = 90 $, the height $L_0, L_1$, stops being a segment, and begins to be an infinite line, what is the current theorem that covers this topic? (Relationship between height $L_0$ and interior angles $ a_0, b_0 $

Comment: Please be consistent with your variables.  I don't see $b$ anywhere except where it is in $a+b \lt 180^\circ$ but $a$ seems to be a length.  If you want to measure in degrees you should use the degree sign, writing 90^\circ to get $90^\circ$.  It looks like $N$ and $m$ are equal.  You use $L$ in the diagram and $l$ in the text.

Comment: The question has to do with the second image really. I mean the relation between the interior angles $ a_0 $ and $ b_0 $ or in the second figure $ a_1 $ and $ b_1 $, with the length of the height $L$

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is $\tan \alpha = \dfrac m{\frac L2}=\frac {2m}L$, which is the first definition of tangent you see.  Your observation is basically that $\tan \alpha \to \infty$ as $\alpha \to \frac \pi 2$

Comment: When the angles are both $90$, that is the parallel lines, the height $L$ transforms, in an infinite line, that I look for. Then is what you answered me?